# How to Close a Window from another window

Tags: javascript, browser

I have 2 windows, winA and winB. From both the window we can open another window, winC. Now winA has logout link. if we click logout it will logout winA, winB and close winC. 
The Problem is when the WinC is opened from WinB, while logOut its not closing the WinC.
Here is the logout code which resides in winA.

```
function logout(logoutUrl){
var winC = window.open('','WinC ');


        if(!winC .closed){
            var logoutWin = window.open(logoutUrl,'Winc','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=350, top=100, width=550, height=400', '');
            setTimeout(function() {
                logoutWin.close();
            }, 1000);
        }
        winC.close();
}
```

The problem is even if winC is not open it calls the logoutUrl and tries to close the winC

Please help.

Comment: You should make `ajax` query to logout instead of this window blink

Comment: Can you give me some example link. I am new to JS.

Comment: It's just `$.get(logoutUrl)` for jQuery.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. But here is the problem. The logoutUrl logs out winC application. Now before calling that we need to check if the winC application window is open or not. If the winC is opened from winA its working perfectly fine. But the problem is if winC is opened from winB. I have no variable to check if the winC is opened from another window.

Answer (score 0):

when coming to the windows, you can name them:

`target='_blank'` creates a new unnamed window

`target='Ralph'` creates a new named window, Ralph, Ralph (mywindow, detail, example etc) can be accessed by javascript.

the window can be closed `<a href='#' onclick='Javascript:Ralph.close();' > Close popup </a>` for most people this will not be neccessary or effective as their popup blocker will not allow javascript to open a new window

Answer (score 0):

You forget the `else` (not sure about the rest of your code or what you are trying to do, but this will only close winC if it is not closed):

```
function logout(logoutUrl){
    var winC = window.open('','WinC ');

    if(!winC.closed){
        var logoutWin = window.open(logoutUrl,'Winc','toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=350, top=100, width=550, height=400', '');
        setTimeout(function() {
            logoutWin.close();
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        winC.close();
    }
}
```